# Hacer un post y abrir la respuesta html en el navegador predeterminado o viceversa (Tampoco entiendo bien como seria lo que quiero hacer) JAVA

Tags: java, html, post

Estoy realizando una app de escritorio en java que analiza la pc del usuario, todos estos datos después quiero que sean desplazados a una landing de mi empresa y que a la vez esta misma se abra en el navegador predeterminado.

He encontrado códigos como el siguiente:

`Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.codigosparadesarrolladores.blogspot.com"));`

¿Pero se podría plantear el post sobre ese new URI?

Comment: Sería mejor si presentaras código sustancial para entender lo que necesitas hacer. Si pudieras compartir lo que has adelantado para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Es que he estado investigando y no encuentro nada parecido a lo que quiero hacer, por lo que no hay código de esta parte (Capaz lo haga con un GET y listo). Yo analizo la pc del usuario y tomo todos los datos de esta. Luego yo quiero abrir la pagina donde el mismo va a seguir completando con sus datos, pero además quiero hacerle un post con los datos recaudados por mi aplicación.